# why i getting this null reference object?

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception

I try to display customer profile on my apps, but these line of code makes app crash when I click on the profile button(profile page)

the error said that Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.EditText.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference

my name and address can be displayed but not my email and my phone number which is weird why it happen like that?

I check my database it contains data, I got stuck here on how to solve my problems because the code can't read my email and phone number but can ready my name and address.

```
public class CustProfileActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextView email;
    EditText name, address, phone;
    Button update;

    DatabaseReference databaseReference;
    FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;
    String userId;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_cust_profile2);

        name = findViewById(R.id.name);
        address = findViewById(R.id.address);
        update = findViewById(R.id.update);


        databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Customer").child("");
        firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        userId = firebaseAuth.getUid();

        databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                Customer cust = dataSnapshot.child(userId).getValue(Customer.class);

                name.setText(cust.name);
                address.setText(cust.home_address);
                phone.setText(cust.telephone_number);
                email.setText(cust.email);

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
```

```
 <TextView
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Phone No"
        android:textSize="13sp"/>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/phone"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />


    <TextView
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Email"
        android:textSize="13dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/email"
        android:hint="email@gmail.com"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

```
public class Customer {
    public String id;
    public  String name;
    public  String email;
    public String home_address;
    public String telephone_number;


    public Customer(){

    }



    public Customer(String id, String name, String email, String home_address, String telephone_number) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.email = email;
        this.home_address = home_address;
        this.telephone_number = telephone_number;
    }
    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getHome_address() {
        return home_address;
    }

    public void setHome_address(String home_address) {
        this.home_address = home_address;
    }

    public String getTelephone_number() {
        return telephone_number;
    }

    public void setTelephone_number(String telephone_number) {
        this.telephone_number = telephone_number;
    }
```

Comment: You forgot to initialize those views. like  name = findViewById(R.id.name);

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Seems like you missed to initialize the `EditText` from layout. Once you initialize then try to perform an action on it.

Your action of setting text on the phone is done prior to the initialization of that view. That's the reason it throws the error

> *void android.widget.EditText.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference*

```
public class CustProfileActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
 ...// ... means rest of your code

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 ...
  // missed to initialize phone & email
  phone = findViewById(R.id.phone);
  email = findViewById(R.id.email);
 ...
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to initialize these views email,phone

so on the onCreate initialize this views by find view by id